# NiFi permission denied while attaching Persistent volume

Tags: kubernetes, apache-nifi, amazon-eks

I've created a NiFi cluster on the AWS EKS. The initial deployment was working fine. Later I attached Persistent volume and persistent volume claim to the NiFi setup. After starting the NiFi, I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[USER_FILE] - openFile(/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs/nifi-user.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs/nifi-user.log (Permission denied)
```

As I'm not an expert in NiFi and Kubernetes, I couldn't identify the issue. It looks like a permission issue on NiFi. The NiFi version I'm using is NiFI 1.15.0.

What may be the possible root cause for this? Is that because NiFi is not using the root user or is that something else?

I'm sharing the full error here:

```
13:56:22,449 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[USER_FILE] - openFile(/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs/nifi-user.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs/nifi-user.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs/nifi-user.log (Permission denied)
    at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.recovery.ResilientFileOutputStream.<init>(ResilientFileOutputStream.java:26)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.openFile(FileAppender.java:204)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.start(FileAppender.java:127)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.start(RollingFileAppender.java:100)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderAction.java:90)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:309)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:193)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:179)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:165)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:152)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:110)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:417)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:362)
    at  at org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi.<init>(RunNiFi.java:145)
    at  at org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi.main(RunNiFi.java:284)
```

I'm also sharing the Kubernetes manifest part that describe the pv and PVC I used for creating the NiFi cluster:

```
        volumeMounts:
          - name: "data"
            mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/data
          - name: "flowfile-repository"
            mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/flowfile_repository
          - name: "content-repository"
            mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/content_repository
          - name: "provenance-repository"
            mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/provenance_repository
          - name: "logs"
            mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs

  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: "data"
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        storageClassName: "gp2"
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
    - metadata:
        name: "flowfile-repository"
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        storageClassName: "gp2"
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
    - metadata:
        name: "content-repository"
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        storageClassName: "gp2"
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
    - metadata:
        name: "provenance-repository"
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        storageClassName: "gp2"
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
    - metadata:
        name: "logs"
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        storageClassName: "gp2"
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 5Gi
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Neron Joseph, did you install [Amazon EBS CSI driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/ebs-csi.html) already?

Comment: Yes, EBS CSI driver is installed on the EKS cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don´t have any issues creating pv and pvc, try to use an extra `initContainers` section to allow the NiFi user with UID and GID 1000 read and write to the provisioned EBS volume:

```yaml
initContainers:
- name: fixmount
  image: busybox
  command: [ 'sh', '-c', 'chown -R 1000:1000 /opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs' ]
  volumeMounts:
  - name: logs
    mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs
```

I hope this will help solve your issues. Here is the official Kubernetes documentation page [Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/).